# Player Respawn and Death when falling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm going through the worse struggle right now. I'm trying to create a game with pitfalls that if the players fall through, they respawn and the game counts their death. I'm completely at wit's end and don't know where to even start with this. The game is 3D

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform spawnPoint; 
    public float minHeightForDeath;
    public GameObject player;

       void Start () {

       }
  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
    if (player.transform.position.y < minHeightForDeath) {
        player.transform.position = spawnPoint;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you specify exactly how your current code is failing? Which of your requirements aren't being met?

Comment: In addition to those details, please provide a screenshot of your player object's properties so there's more information readers can work with.

Comment: Unity console is saying that I can't convert unity.engine.transform to unity.engine.vector3

Comment: Baethor, you need to use the `spawnPoint.position`.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! It worked!!

Comment: @Baethor For future reference, please be certain to include any error messages in your question next time - they often lead to the solution quickly, and reduce the likelihood of users answering blindly.

Comment: I understand, I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a collider on a plane/cube/whatever works for you, and set it to be a trigger. So when they pass through [the trigger collider](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers), it can record them and do what you want with it.

Use the [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) method script

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    other.transform.position = spawnPoint.position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting any data in the "minHeightForDeath" float. Unless you do it in the editor.

Other than that, have you put the script on the player gameObject? And have you set what you have to in the editor?

Comment: I tried to put the data in using the editor, but for some reason, something isn't allowing me to do so. I attached it to my player gameObject.